# Can't install Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 or Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I trying update my VS2013 instance to Update 5 but when click on online installer don't do anything in my %temp% setup write this log:

```
[194C:1964][2016-06-10T15:54:58]i001: Burn v3.7.3424.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\VS2013.5.exe, cmdline: ''
[194C:1964][2016-06-10T15:54:58]e000: Error 0x80040111: Failed to load manifest as XML document.
[194C:1964][2016-06-10T15:54:58]e000: Error 0x80040111: Failed to load manifest.
[194C:1964][2016-06-10T15:54:58]e000: Error 0x80040111: Failed to initialize core.
```

I tried install new 2015 version but error is very similar

```
[1BD0:09E4][2016-06-10T15:54:55]i000: === Logging started: 2016-06-10T15:54:55+00:00 === 
[1BD0:09E4][2016-06-10T15:54:55]i000: Bootstrapper v14.0.5995.28262, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), command line: "C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\vs_community_ENU.exe" 
[1BD0:09E4][2016-06-10T15:54:55]e000: Error 0x80040111: Failed to load configuration data into XML document.
[1BD0:09E4][2016-06-10T15:54:55]e000: Error 0x80040111: Failed to read configuration data from process module.
[1BD0:09E4][2016-06-10T15:54:55]e000: Error 0x80040111: Failed to load configuration data from process module.
[1BD0:09E4][2016-06-10T15:54:56]i000: Process exit code: 0x80040111 (-2147221231)
```

I searched on Google but can't find any good solution, I already tried install MSXML 3.0 and MSXML 4.0 SP3 but problem persist. Any idea?

Comment: My guess is that you have/has file system corruption that has mangled your .Net install.  have you run a chkdsk and SFC yet?

Comment: Yes and SFC repaired some files, chkdsk is ok.